# Exercise IV.4.6. (c) Logic for Mathematicians by Rosser $\vdash P_m \supset P_1\vee P_2\vee \cdots \vee P_n$ if $1 \leq m \leq n$.

Tags: propositional-calculus

The instructions state "using only results of Sec. 4 or earlier portions of the present exercise, prove:"
We have shown already the following: (a) $\vdash P\vee Q \supset Q \vee P$ and (b) $\vdash P \supset P \vee Q$.

We still haven't establish associativity for the "or" connective, and we are supposed to assume association from left to right. So $P_1\vee P_2\vee \cdots \vee P_n$ is something like $(\cdots (((P_1 \vee P
_2)\vee P_3)\vee \cdots)\vee P_n)$.

There are 29 Theorems that we have established in Sec. 4, I am hoping that the reader has access to the book. Two theorems that I think might be useful are:

Theorem IV.4.18. $\vdash P_1 P_2 \cdots P_n\supset P_m$ for $1\leq m\leq n$ , and Theorem IV.4.7. $\sim P \supset \sim Q \vdash Q \supset P$

But, I can't think of how to apply Theorem IV.4.18. to $P_1\vee P_2\vee \cdots \vee P_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a special case: $n=4$, $m=3$. We want to show $\vdash P_3\supset (((P_1\vee P_2)\vee P_3)\vee P_4)$.

- We know already that $\vdash P_3\supset ((P_1\vee P_2)\vee P_3)$.
- And we know that $\vdash((P_1\vee P_2)\vee P_3)\supset(((P_1\vee P_2)\vee P_3)\supset P_4)$.

So all we need is "$\vdash A\supset B$ and $\vdash B\supset C$ implies $\vdash A\supset C$" . . .

The general problem is solved using essentially the same structure, plus induction.